# Exception safety constructor

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management

In my small programm i need to have a class with some dynamic allocated data, like this one:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(size_t aSize1, size_t aSize2)
    :mX1(new char[aSize1]),
    mX2(new char[aSize2])
  {}
  ~MyClass()
  {
    delete[] mX1;
    delete[] mX2;
  }
...
private:
  MyClass(const MyClass& aObj);
  MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& aObj);

private:
  char* mX1;
  char* mX2;
};
```

The first question is, if i ought to use raw pointers, is the constructor of my class exception safety? I mean, is there any toruble in case if `new` throws an exception when allocating memory for `mX2`? In this case memory, that already allocated to `mX1` will leak or correctly deleted?

The second question is, what will be better - to use some smart pointer (e.g. unique_ptr) or to use stl container (e.g. vector) to hold dynamic array?

UPD. If i'll use unique_ptr, `std::unique_ptr<char[]> mX1;` how should i implement copy constructor?

Comment: Dynamic arrays are a misfeature of C++ that you shouldn't really use. Exceptions are one reason. Another reason is that the pointer to the first element that you're getting back from `new[]` is useless without the size information, so you end up storing that information redundantly and non-locally. A class like `std::vector` is "dynamic arrays done right" (if you don't mind the extra word for the capacity); dynamic arrays are much better done in library than in the core language.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a good idea to handle exceptions in constructors. But when you have ran out of memory you are up a certain creek without a certain instrument. There is little you can do.
2. Use smart pointers/vectors etc. Takes the hassle out of life.

Comment: I would bet that idiom (about the creek and the instrument) is pretty confusing for a non-native English speaker (which I think the OP is), especially the way you've obfuscated it.